# How to get particular field val in joined RDD in spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

census(Id:String, Emptype:String,Salary:Int)
incometax(EMptype:String,Slab:Int)

After joining these two RDD.How can I filter the values where salary is greater than  50,000 along with other fields in joined table? (In spark scala)

Comment: `joinedDf.filter(col("salary") > 50000).filter(col("EmpType") === lit("Employee"))`.

Though there are other options to do that to - using lambda function, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` or `where` to filter data from DataFrame. Check below code.

```
scala> case class Census(id:String, emptype:String, salary:Int)
defined class Census

scala> case class Incometax(emptype:String,slab:Int)
defined class Incometax

scala> val censusDF = Seq(Census("1","a",10000),Census("2","b",20000),Census("3","c",60000)).toDF
censusDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: string, emptype: string ... 1 more field]

scala> val incometaxDF = Seq(Incometax("a",10),Incometax("b",15),Incometax("c",20)).toDF
incometaxDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [emptype: string, slab: int]

scala> censusDF.join(incometaxDF,Seq("emptype"),"left").filter(censusDF("salary") > 50000).show(false)
+-------+---+------+----+
|emptype|id |salary|slab|
+-------+---+------+----+
|c      |3  |60000 |20  |
+-------+---+------+----+

scala> censusDF.join(incometaxDF,Seq("emptype"),"left").where(censusDF("salary") > 50000).show(false)
+-------+---+------+----+
|emptype|id |salary|slab|
+-------+---+------+----+
|c      |3  |60000 |20  |
+-------+---+------+----+
```